# Firebase reset password link showed me error on the screen

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I tried both the custom action URL as well as the default URL *.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler, but no luck.

Both cases show the same error on the screen after clicking the link.
[image]

It says "The requested action is invalid."

Also I checked the console log, it says "Request is missing required data".
[image]

I also checked my GCP admin panel, and make sure there is no restriction to the browser key.
[image]

Where could possibly go wrong? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I found the answer. I misused the action URL.

What I used previously was: `https://mywebsite.com/__/auth/handler`

Correct one should be: `https://mywebsite.com/__/auth/action`